# Passing 2D vector to a funtion

Tags: c++, stl

If I declare a vector like this,

```
vector <int> v[100];
```

How to pass it to a function and receive it as a argument in that function?

I tried using this,

```
void foo(vector <int>& v) {
..
}
main() {
..
foo(v);
}
```

Comment: How would you pass an array of anything to a function? It doesn't matter that its an array of vector.

Comment: Since you're already using a `vector`, why use a raw array of vectors instead of a `vector<vector<int>>`?

Comment: You should expand on your use case. Do you need to store a list of 2D points? If so, you may need `std::vector< std::pair<int, int> >` or define a Point or Vector class. Or do you need to hold a matrix?

Comment: If you wanted one vector containing 100 zeroes, you'd need `vector<int> v(100)`. That is `( )` not `[ ]`

Answer (score 0):

First off, use `typedef`, or better still `using`, if you are working with a newer C++ version.

```
typedef vector<int> twoD_vector[100];
// or alternatively (better)
using twoD_vector = vector<int>[100];
```

Then, don't use old style C-arrays ([100]). Use std::array (or boost::array) instead. It has `std::iterators`, has a `std::container` interface, comes with bounds-checking `array.at(idx)` and has other good features.

```
typedef std::array<std::vector<int>, 100> twoD_vector;
```

With the new type `twoD_vector` usage is a snap, like this.

```
twoD_vector v;

void foo(twoD_vector &val)
{
    // iterate over the 100 'outer' elements
    for (size_t i=0; i<val.size(); ++i) {
        // iterate over each element of the inner vector
        std::vector<int> &inner_vector(val[i]);
        printf("%u: size is %u", i, inner_vector.size());
        for (size_t j=0; j<inner_vector.size(); ++j) {
            // do something with the integer
            printf("inner vector[%u] has value %d\n", j, inner_vector[j]);
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
   foo(v);
}
```

P.S. This is straight from my head, there might be syntax or program errors in the code snippet, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: Why don't you use `cout`?

Answer (score 0):

what you have is a array of vectors, which is fine is one of your dimensions is fixed to 100.

i'd recommend to actually use a 2d vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;

void foo(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v) 
{
   ...  
}
```